# PersistenceMode vs. Storing property in ViewState

Tags: asp.net, properties, persistence, viewstate

What is the difference in utility/performance between using PersistenceMode on a property and storing the value of said property in ViewState in an ASP.NET web page?

This:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public int ClientUno { get; private set; }
```

versus this:

```
    public int ClientUno
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["ClientUno"] == null) return 0;
            else return (int)(ViewState["ClientUno"]);
        }
        set { ViewState["ClientUno"] = value; }
    }
```

I have done some googling around the internets and can't figure this one out.  It seems like this would have come up before - I just can't find the answer.  Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PersistanceMode` has nothing to do with storing data in a `ViewState`. It is used to create custom *server* controls and affects server code.
For example see: [How do I make a control with a child control collection in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825227/how-do-i-make-a-control-with-a-child-control-collection-in-asp-net)